# HTML5: using <p style> with color and font?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML5, and used to program a lot in HTML4. Obviously, the `<font>` tag is deprecated now, and I discovered you can use the `<p style="">` tag in HTML5 without using CSS.

My issue is that I am trying to use both `<p style="color:">` and `<p style="font-family:'Verdana'>` at the same time, like the attached image.

Any help?

[image: code]

Comment: `<p style="color: green; font-family: 'Verdana';">`

Comment: `<p style="...">` **is** CSS, it's just not an extra file. That's why it is called *inline* CSS. In CSS you separate multiple properties with semi-colons. This applies to CSS files exactly like it applies to the `style` attribute.

Comment: _"I discovered you can use the <p style=""> tag in HTML5 without using CSS"_. You _can_, but you _shouldn't_.

Answer (score 1):

- HTML doesn't allow paragraphs to be nested
- `key: value` pairs in CSS can be separated by semi-colons (`;`) - you don't need multiple elements to have multiple properties
- Stylesheets are much easier to manage than style attributes

```css
p {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>This is a test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple inline styles for an element. In your case:

```
<p style = "color: green; font-family: verdana;"> This is the body </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use inline CSS then you can do it like this:
Just separate with ";"

```
<p style="color:green;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif">This is a heading</p>
```

It is better practice to use a sepatate CSS file, however sometimes this i not an option so use the above method.

Both options wiht examples can be found on W3 schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp